# Android: How To sort table values in Sqlite (Based on the extension of the String value)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am having a database table (Table1) which has 3 columns (ID,NAME,SIZE). The column, ID will have values like 1,2,3,... and coressponding values of NAME will be Abc.pdf,aaa.txt,abcc.doc,... ,.

My question is , I need to write a query which will group table according to the coloumn NAME i.e, For example, below is my sample table

1. Abc.pdf  20
2. aaa.txt  1
3. abcc.doc 10
4. ac.pdf  25

My query should give me

1. Abc.pdf  20
2. ac.pdf  25
3. aaa.txt  1
4. abcc.doc 10

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:
I would suggest storing the file types as a separate column, since that seems to be what you want the rows to be grouped by. Afterwards, you can simply concatenate the file type back onto the end of the file name.

```
Cursor cursor = database.query("Table1", null, null, null, null, null, FILE_TYPE + " DESC");
```

The method documentation can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)